# Class field as array of objects

Tags: php, oop

i've declared the next class:

```
class Background{ 
    protected $users = array() ;
 ......
 }
```

and I employ `$users` as array of `User()` , which is another object i've created.
The problem comes up when I try to use this method :

```
function createB(){
        foreach($this->users as $user){
            $name = $user->getName();
        }
    }
```

And `$user->getName()` is actually an error becuase `$user` is not seen as an object.
What might be the reason for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you cut your question off before it finished.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: and where is the class `User`?

Comment: may be the reason that `$user` is the just internal array pointer.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->users);` shows?

Comment: You didn't fill the `$users` array with `User` objects. Example: `$users[0] = new User('awesome username');` that's why the not a object error pops up because NULL isn't a object :P

Comment: Is it that hard to post entire code you use? If `$user` is not an object, then you didn't fill the variable correctly and there's your problem. Since you didn't post the piece of code that does that, how can anyone help you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with the $users not actually getting populated
Try adding this to prevent this sort of issue. if this doesn't help, please add information as to how $users is populated.

```
function createB()
{
    if(!empty($this->users))
    {
        foreach($this->users as $user)
        {
            if($user instanceof User)
            {
                $name = $user->getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```